# Consequences of not using a lang attribute in an html5 html tag

Tags: html

If at the start of my html5 doc I simply use:

`<!DOCTYPE html><html>`

how will my site be at a disadvantage for not using something like:

`<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good question, but I think most of what you want to know is simple reference:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html

Some highlights:

> Language information specified via the
>   lang attribute may be used by a user
>   agent to control rendering in a
>   variety of ways. Some situations where
>   author-supplied language information
>   may be helpful include:
>
> - Assisting search engines
> - Assisting speech synthesizers
> - Helping a user agent select glyph variants for high quality typography
> - Helping a user agent choose a set of quotation marks
> - Helping a user agent make decisions about hyphenation,
>     ligatures, and spacing
> - Assisting spell checkers and grammar checkers

I don't believe there are any important differences between HTML4 and HTML5 regarding this.