# Is <html lang="en"> important?

Tags: html, css

I just wanted to ask if the  tag is really that important... Do I need to use it if I am developing a website?
Will it affect my code if I don't put it?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399018/consequences-of-not-using-a-lang-attribute-in-an-html5-html-tag

Answer (score 1):

It's important for accessibility reasons, not codewise.
It's mainly used for translations "bot".

If you really want it to be perfect, then use `<html lang="en-US">` or the appropriate country code for your language (like mine is `fr-FR`and not `fr-CA` since there are differencies between those two languagues).

Comment: Thank you, I have a question what you wrote. What's the difference if I write en-US but I lived in the UK ( en-GB). Can I still write en-US?

Comment: You can, if you write in US english. There are a few differences (color vs colour) and those differences are deadly for bots if you set it wrong. The thing is that if you write in UK english you put `en-GB`, if you write in US english then you put `en-US`